# Continuous Audio recording in Java via line-in or microphone inputs

Tags: java, audio, hardware, audio-recording, javasound

Would it be possible to monitor the mic input of a sound card to record audio when audio is actually "heard"/present?  Mic input comes from a VHF radio speaker output, so audio will only be "present" when radio transmissions are received.  If possible, how could this be achieved in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a microcontroller to look for the signal receive strenght and when the signal is over the threshold just sent a signal to "record" the audio??

Comment: Sounds like the way to do it...this is going to be done in a Raspberry Pi, so I might use the GPIO pins as the suggested microcontroller part. That part solved, how do I record audio in java?